# Confused with behavior of this procedure

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, prediction, r5rs

(CONTEXT)

I've defined a procedure that applies another one-argument procedure object to it's parameter twice. Take for example the procedure inc that adds 1 to it's argument, (double inc) will add two. hence ((double inc) 5) returns 7.

(THE PROBLEM)

I expected for (((double (double double)) inc) 5) to return 13. Since double double will apply a procedure 4 times and thus the most-left double will result in a the application of the one-parameter procedure 8 times. A lineair growth.

I'm wrong. Look below for what the procedure actually returns.

Clearly i'm missing something and there's a flaw in my understanding.

```
(define (double proc)
(lambda (y) (proc (proc y))))

(define (inc x) (+ x 1))

> ((double inc) 5)
7
> (((double double) inc) 5)
9
> (((double (double double)) inc) 5)
21
> (((double (double (double double))) inc) 5)
261    
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fairly easy to deduct using both reason or substitution model.

## Reason:

```
(double double)
```

This is like double but twice, quadrouple. When applied with a function it will apply that function 4 times.

```
(double (double double))
```

This is doubling quadrouple. The result of quadrouple will be quadroupled making it 4*4. When applied with a function it will apply that 16 times.

```
(double (double (double double)))
```

This is doubling the previous one. Then the same again. 16*16 makes it apply the result 256 times.

Thus `(double double)` is `2^2`, `(double (double double))` is `(2^2)^2` and `(double (double (double double)))` is `((2^2)^2)^2` or `2^8` for short.

This relates to lambda calculus where power is defined as `λb.λe.e b` or `(lambda (b) (lambda (e) (e b))`. Now `double` is the church numeral for `2`. Do you see that you are doing `((2^2)^2)^2`?

## Substitution

Here are the expressions reduced. I sometimes jump steps later since it's pretty much the same that happens several times.

```
((double inc) 5)               ; ==>
((lambda (y) (inc (inc y))) 5) ; ==>
(inc (inc 5))                  ; ==> 7


(((double double) inc) 5)                   ; ==>
(((lambda (y) (double (double y))) inc) 5)  ; ==>
(((lambda (y) (double (double y))) inc) 5)  ; ==>
((double (double inc)) 5)                   ; ==>
((double (lambda (y) (inc (inc y)))) 5)     ; ==>
((lambda (y) ((lambda (y) (inc (inc y))) ((lambda (y) (inc (inc y))) y))) 5) ; ==>
((lambda (y) (inc (inc (inc (inc y))))) 5) ; ==>
(inc (inc (inc (inc 5)))) ; ==> 9


(((double (double double)) inc) 5)                                                                ; ==>
(((double (lambda (y) (double (double y)))) inc) 5)                                               ; ==>
(((lambda (y) ((lambda (y) (double (double y))) ((lambda (y) (double (double y))) y))) inc) 5)    ; ==>
(((lambda (y) (double (double (double (double y))))) inc) 5)                                      ; ==>
((double (double (double (lambda (y) (inc (inc y)))))) 5)                                         ; ==>
((double (double (lambda (y) (inc (inc (inc (inc y))))))) 5)                                      ; ==>
(inc (inc (inc (inc (inc (inc (inc (inc (inc (inc (inc (inc (inc (inc (inc (inc 5)))))))))))))))) ; ==> 21
```

I'll leave the last one as an exercise.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your interpretation of what `double` expands to when nested.

Just apply substitution of `y` with `inc`, one level at a time, and you'll see what's happening:

`(double inc)` expansion using `let` to make things clearer:

```
(lambda (y)
        (let ([proc inc])
             ((proc (proc y))))
```

So far, so good.

`((double double) inc)` expansion:

```
     (lambda (y)
        (let ([proc (lambda (y_0) (double (double y_0)))])
             (proc (proc y))))
```

The first application works as intended, but the second doubles not the application of the `inc` function, but of the `double` function itself, as you apply `double` to the function `double` in `(double double)`.

If you do it again, i.e. `((double (double double) inc)`, you can see it gets messy...

What you're probably looking for is to apply the result of a single application of `double` to the result of another single application...

As in:

```
> ((double (double (double inc))) 5)
13
> ((double (double (double (double inc)))) 5)
21
```